# Java and Jython integration issue with method names

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm following the instruction in [Jython and Java Integration](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html).

The idea is simple; make Java interface, and matching python class.
The issue is that with a interface function setX(), and setY(), I always get an error when I execute the file. I had to modify the name to such as setXvalue() or setYvalue() to avoid the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class    
org.python.core.PyTraceback
at org.python.core.PyException.tracebackHere(PyException.java:158)

at org.python.core.PyObject._jcall(PyObject.java:3587)
at org.python.proxies.Arith$Arith$0.setX(Unknown Source) <-- ERROR???
at Main.main(Main.java:14)

package org.jython.book.interfaces;
```

This is a Java interface.

```
public interface ArithType {

    public void setX(int x); // <-- Error
    public void setYa(int x);
    public int getXa();
    public int getYa();
    public int add();
}
```

This is partial python class.

```
class Arith(ArithType):
    ''' Class to hold building objects '''

    def setX(self, x): # << Error
        self.x = x
```

You can find the source to test at this site - 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/2013/Archive.zip

What's wrong with this? Why the method name setX() or setY() causes an error in execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with accessing attributes of an object in Jython; Jython uses implicit getters/setters, so reading from `self.x` invokes `self.getX()` and so on. Changing all occurrences of `self.x` to `self._x` (ditto for `y`) in your jython code made it work (for me). It is actually a convention in Python to name non-public members as `_...`.